# Trying to find Big Theta notation of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSYCg.png)

I am very confused by how to figure out this algorithm. Hmmmm. I have thought about it. My friend tells me its nlogn because of the outer while and for loop becomes n while the inner while loop of course is log n. But I'm not 100% convinced. Any ideas?

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: Hello Ken. Will do. But do you know if this is a gemoetric progression type of problem? And is that why the outer loops equal n. I was thinking the outer two loops would equal log^2 n. But maybe my thinking is flawed.

Comment: There is no code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Very inner loop (while (k <= N) ) is logN. Then outer loop loops 'i' times. 'i' starts by N then decreases 2 times each loop until it reaches 1.

Answer is (N*logN + (N/2)*logN + (N/4)*logN + ... + 1*logN).

(N + (N/2) + (N/4) + ... + 1) can be simplified as 2N-1. Answer is O(logN * (2N-1)).

Comment: Oh thanks. I was never formally taught how to check complexity rigorously. From your explanation, we first start with the inner most loop and work outward through its dependencies?